# WinAppDriver: Is it possible to create By instance of AccessibilityId (Automation ID)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, winappdriver

I am new with the WinAppDriver tool and not clear about how to create By instance  AccessibilityId (Automation ID) as there is not straight forward option to achieve this.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. May be you need to rephrase and elaborate. Try adding the piece of code which is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
By idToFind = ByAccessibilityId.AccessibilityId("string value");
var element = _driver.FindElement(idToFind);
```